# Automation of email after success or failure of Jobs through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am a newbie to Jenkins,I have been trying to trigger an email after my batch commands are successful in  a particular format, I'm almost done but I need to get the count of the passed and failures jobs , I'm unable to get a sum of the failures and the passed jobs separately , I have injected few variables ,tried the  arithmetic operators inside the batch commands using the injected variables but I'm not able to get the sum , I'm getting something like "1+1+1" and not the actual sum.Your help will be highly appreciated ,I have been trying hard to figure this out. Thank you in advance.

**Update**

I have injected a variable say `STATUS` and in windows batch command I'm using some code `|| exit /b 0 set /a x=1 set /a ${STATUS}=%STATUS%+%x%` for storing the incremented count. I have six batch commands so I want to store the sum of the failure and success count which is currently not happening , the `STATUS` value is like `"1+1+1"` and not the actual sum.

Also I tried with a different approach wherein I have written the code inside the HTML tags.  Earlier I was using the HTML just for the structuring of the table. I put in my code within the earlier HTML code.

```
if (${A_STATUS}==FAILED) { ${FAILURE_COUNT}+=1 ${SUCCESS_COUNT}-=1 } 
else if (${B_STATUS}==FAILED) { ${FAILURE_COUNT}+=1 ${SUCCESS_COUNT}-=1 }
```

at the end I'm printing the success and failure counts:

```
<tr> <td style="color:Green;">${SUCCESS_COUNT}</td>
     <td style="color:Red;">${FAILURE_COUNT}</td>
     <td>6</td>
</tr>
```

this too isn't working.

Comment: Please post the code that is not working.

Comment: I have injected a variable say "STATUS" and in windows batch command I'm using *some code* || exit /b 0 set /a x=1  set /a ${STATUS}=%STATUS%+%x% for storing the incremented count.I have six batch commands so I want to store the sum of the failure and success count which is currently not happening , the STATUS value is like"1+1+1" and not the actual sum. further details in the next comment.

Comment: Also I tried with a different approach wherein I have written the code inside the HTML tags.Earlier I was using the HTML just for the structuring of the table. I put in my code within the earlier HTML code.if (${A_STATUS}==FAILED) {
${FAILURE_COUNT}+=1
${SUCCESS_COUNT}-=1
}
else if (${B_STATUS}==FAILED) {
${FAILURE_COUNT}+=1
${SUCCESS_COUNT}-=1
} at the end im printing the success and failure counts : <tr>
<td style="color:Green;">${SUCCESS_COUNT}</td>
<td style="color:Red;">${FAILURE_COUNT}</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr> this too isn't working.